# Share Google Cloud Storage Bucket across Projects

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I want a storage bucket to be owned by multiple projects, without the use of a service account. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Storage buckets can only belong to a single project, and that project will foot the bill for that bucket. Permissions can absolutely span multiple accounts, though. Any permission for a user or a group that can be applied to a bucket in one project can also be applied to a bucket in another project.

What exactly are you hoping to do?

Comment: Ok, that's fine. How do I get the bucket to show up in multiple projects then? I add the same user that owns buckets in another project and still am not able to see the bucket from the other project.

Comment: What do you mean "show up"? Do you mean in the Cloud Console? It won't show up in their list of buckets for their own project, since its not a part of their project, but if you've granted them permission, they could go directly to https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/YOUR_BUCKET_NAME

Comment: 'Show up' in the cloud console is exactly what I mean. I can't imagine why it wouldn't be displayed there. Every file sharing service that I can think of (Google Drive, Box, OneDrive) has this behaviour, which is basically what GCP Storage is. How else would members of other projects know what they have access to?

Comment: google cloud storage isn't a file sharing service.  It's for storing files.  Access control on something like that has to support other usage models than sharing files with other orgs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can automatically push a 'bucket' to another user's console, in another project.

I do think you could have your users mount a shared bucket using gcsfuse. Somewhere outside of the console.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse

Then when you add 'stuff' to the bucket, it would show up in their mounted folder just like DropBox, Google Drive, Box, OneDrive etc.

With those other projects you mentioned.  You don't get to automatically push folders into the folder of another user, similarly you can't automatically push a 'bucket' into the 'project' of another user.

But you can offer a share, that the users have the option of using.